# memory problems due to Github repository's .git folder

Tags: git, github, memory, repository

I need to remove the size of the `.git` folder in my personal repository due to memory problems. Especially, the subfolder `.git/objects` and `.git/lfs` consume a lot of memory. Can I remove the folder or the subfolders without damaging the functionality of the repository?

Comment: What do you mean by `memory problems`? You should normally *never* touch anything in the `.git` directory.

Comment: Note that at least in English language programming, we distinguish between "memory" (RAM and the like: a Mac laptop might have 16 GB of "memory") and "disk space" (this same Mac laptop might have 500 GB or 1 TB of "disk space"). Data in `.git/objects` and `.git/lfs` consumes *disk space*, not memory.

Comment: Many thanks for the comment on the difference between memory and disk space. My problem relates to disk space: The repository is located on our computer cluster. I exceed the limit of disk space that is allocated to me and most of the space is consumed by the ```.git``` directory

Answer (score 1):

Don't touch `.git/objects` because that's where git store the data and you will break the repository. You could probably reduce a little the size by doing a `git gc`

For `.git/lfs`, you could run a `git lfs prune`
https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-prune.1.ronn

Comment: I cannot use git gc due to the disk space restriction, that is, in the course to optimize the repository, some data would be written on the disk, but I cannot write anymore. There are now some big files in ```.git/objects/pack```, e.g. ```tmp_pack_JU4S3a```. Can I delete the tmp files?